# Square Refund cURL to JavaScript Request Not Found.. Google App Script

Tags: javascript, curl, google-apps-script, square

I'm trying to issue a refund through the square API using JavaScript (Google App Script) and getting the following 400 response and error

```
"{"errors": [{"code": "VALUE_EMPTY","detail": "Field must not be blank","field": "idempotency_key","category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"},{"code": "MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail": "Field must be..."
```

Here is the code, very similar to PayPal that IS working

```
const head = 
    {
        'Square-Version': "2020-06-25",
        'Authorization': authorization,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    var data = 
    {
        'idempotency_key': rentalID,
        'payment_id': paymentID,
        'reason': reason,
        'amount_money': 
        {
            'amount': refundAmount,
            'currency': "USD"
        }
    }

    const params = 
    {
        headers: head,
        method: "post",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payLoad: JSON.stringify(data)
    }

    const endpoint = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/refunds';

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, params);

    var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
    var responseBody = response.getContentText();
    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    if (responseCode === 200)
    {
        responseJSON.error = false;
        return responseJSON;
    }
    else
    {
        responseJSON.error = true;
        responseJSON.message = `Request failed. Expected 200, got ${responseCode}: ${responseBody}`;
        return responseJSON;
    }
```

I followed https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/refunds/refund-payment which has a cURL example

```
idempotency_key = '999',
payment_id = a valid square payment
amount: 1
reason: 'rental return'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the property name payLoad for a UrlFetchApp in GAS.

Once I changed

```
payLoad: JSON.stringify(data)
```

To

```
payload: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Everything worked. A sad spending of 5 hours on this problem.